# `Stack` do not display content which are not within the area of its first Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to make a scrollable UI in flutter. I added a `ListView` and then inside it a `Stack`.
Below is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

var scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text('Drawer Header'),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Item 1'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Item 2'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: <Widget>[TestPageUI()],
        ),
      ),
      key: scaffoldKey,
    );
  }
}

class TestPageUI extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return TestPageState();
  }
}

class TestPageState extends State<TestPageUI> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .30,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: ClipPath(
            clipper: ClippingClass(),
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .30,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      image: AssetImage("assets/images/morning_image.png"))),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SafeArea(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.menu,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  print("clicked");
                  scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
                },
              ),
              Spacer(
                flex: 2,
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.notifications,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .2,
          left: 0.0,
          right: 0.0,
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Container(
              child: Text(
                "Good Morning, Fred",
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .headline
                    .apply(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .3,
          left: 0.0,
          right: 0.0,
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .22,
                  height: 100,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.asset(
                        "assets/icons/car_service.png",
                        width: 48,
                        height: 48,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        child: Text(
                          "ONE",
                          style: Theme.of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .caption
                              .apply(color: Colors.black),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Spacer(
                  flex: 1,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .22,
                  height: 100,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.asset(
                        "assets/icons/car_service.png",
                        width: 48,
                        height: 48,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        child: Text(
                          "FOUR",
                          style: Theme.of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .caption
                              .apply(color: Colors.black),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .54,
          left: 0.0,
          right: 0.0,
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 100,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, left: 10, right: 10),
                  child: _createAdvertisement(),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _createAdvertisement() {
    return Card(
      elevation: 4.0,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            placeholder: "https://picsum.photos/200",
            image: "https://picsum.photos/200",
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            width: double.infinity,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .9 / 4,
          ),
          
          
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }
}

class ClippingClass extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width / 4, size.height - 30, size.width / 2, size.height - 30);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width - (size.width / 4), size.height - 30,
        size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

There is an issue, below is the output

[image]

You can see that after the top background image, there is no content. The container holding the top background image is 30% of the height. whatever not within its area, will not get displayed. However if you increase its height, the rest of the content will get displayed as well as the background image size will increase.

What is wrong in here? How to display the content below the 30% height without an issue?

Also please note that I have another `ListView` at the end of the code. I do not want this `ListView` to scroll by its own, because the top `ListView` does the job of scrolling the full page.

Answer (score 1):

Use `overflow:Overflow.visible` inside Stack()
like this-

```
Stack(overflow: Overflow.visible,
      child:.....)
```

Comment: overflow is deprecated use `clipBehavior: Clip.none`